# Dropout only on specific column in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am training an autoencoder using keras,with the encoder part as :

```
    self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential()
    self.encoder.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))
    self.encoder.add(layers.Dense(14, activation='relu'))
    self.encoder.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'))
```

I am using Dropout at the start to create noise.My input is a 14-dimensional dataset.What dropout does now is dropping randomly each time 20% of the nodes meaning dropping 20% of the features at each time.What i would like to do is drop a specific feature,let's say feature_3(i suppose this means dropping a specific node),with a probability of 20% in each training step.

Could this be done using Keras?

If yes then how?

Answer (score 1):

I do think you misunderstand how Dropout works.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dropout

Your expectations is what dropout actually is. Also keras.layers.Dropout does not "create noise"

If you'd like to set the dropout mask:

> `noise_shape`:    1D integer tensor representing the shape of the binary dropout mask that will be multiplied with the input. For instance, if your inputs have shape (batch_size, timesteps, features) and you want the dropout mask to be the same for all timesteps, you can use noise_shape=(batch_size, 1, features).

Note that `noise_shape` describes the behavior of the feature's dropout and is not related to adding/substracting noise to your features.

Comment: I think right now Dropout is applied to all 14 features.What i would like is for it to be applied with a probability of 20% to only 1 of them